# How to detect state of checklist item using Trello API

Tags: trello

I'd like to see some sort of 'state' field on each item in the checklist object returned from a query in this form:

```
https://api.trello.com/1/checklists/[checklist_id]

# Response:

{u'checkItems': [{u'id': u'blahblahblah1',
                  u'name': u'Some checklist item',
                  u'pos': 424242,
                  u'type': u'check'},
                 {etc..}
]}
```

Also, it seems that the following method does return the state, but only for completed checklist items:

```
https://api.trello.com/1/cards/[card_id]/checkItemStates

# Response:

[{"idCheckItem":"blahblahblah1","state":"complete”},
 {“idCheckItem":"blahblahblah2","state":"complete"},
 {"idCheckItem":"blahblahblah3","state":"complete”},
 {“idCheckItem":"blahblahblah4","state":"complete"}]
```

So does this mean that the results of several queries have to be synthesized in order to get an accurate view of the state of all the checklist on a given card?  I'd love to get all the information about all checklists (including the state of each item) on a card in a single query.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the `/checkItems` switch to the path, you will see the states for each item:

```
/1/checklists/[checkListId]/checkitems?key=[your appKey]
```

Returns:

```
[
    {"state":"complete","id":"XXX","name":"hex support","pos":16804},
    {"state":"incomplete","id":"XXX","name":"funky chars","pos":33233}
]
```

They have since added it to the base call (as you have it) as well.